# Changing the raster layer symbology in QGIS with PyQGIS is not reflected in the layer properties. How to fix this?

Tags: raster, pyqgis, qgis-3, coding-style

I have managed to alter the raster layer symbology, even creating my own symbologies, in its different variants 'multibandcolor', 'paletted', 'singlebandpseudocolor' and 'singlebandgray'.

Changes are reflected in the view **but not in the layer properties**. **How to fix this?**

I leave a code example to assign three classification ranges to a raster, with red, yellow and blue colors:

```
capa=iface.activeLayer()
provider=capa.dataProvider()
#Statistics
stat= provider.bandStatistics(1)
max =stat.maximumValue
min=stat.minimumValue
#Defining the three ranges
range = max - min
add = range/2
interval = min + add

#new renderizador
sha = QgsRasterShader()
shaf = QgsColorRampShader()
lst=[]  

colDic = {'red':'#ff0000', 'yellow':'#ffff00','blue':'#0000ff'}
valueList =[min, interval, max]

lst= [QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[0],QColor(colDic['red'])),\
QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[1],QColor(colDic['yellow'])),\
QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[2],QColor(colDic['blue']))]

shaf.setColorRampItemList(lst) 
shaf.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.Interpolated) 
sha.setRasterShaderFunction(shaf) 

pseudoRenderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(provider, capa.type(),sha)                                         
capa.setRenderer(pseudoRenderer) 
capa.triggerRepaint()
```

[image]

**Note:** *with the createShader method if the changes are reflected in both the view and Layers properties, but I have no control to assign the ranges of values*

Comment: You didn't mention which QGIS version you're using. It should work on QGIS v3.16.x

Comment: Thank you German, in developing the QGIS3.4 code, to give you as much compatibility as possible. I will try it on 3.10. If it works on 3.16 it must be a bug. **By the way, it's great what you share in your github** on PyQGIS, of a very high level for Spanish speaking

Comment: Yep, testing your code on QGIS 3.16 gave me the expected results, so most likely it was a bug that is already fixed. (And thanks for the comment about what I share via GitHub!)

Comment: In QGIS3.10 it does not work!! Please @Germán Carrillo, in QGIS3.16 the change in the properties dialog box? is reflected in the symbology option?

Comment: This is what I get running your code on QGIS 3.16.x: https://i.imgur.com/oh0UQXb.png

Comment: Oh, I see, it works perfectly, I guess you added the labels to the code. Undoubtedly it is a bug, there is no possible solution for previous versions. Thank you very much!